# how to block a search engine to search from my domain

Tags: search-engine, server

I want to block a search engine to stop indexing my website. I've followed this reference [Here](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/restricting-bots/how-to-stop-search-engines-from-crawling-your-website) and create a robot.txt on root. Content is this:

```
User-agent: http://search.pch.com 
Disallow: /
```

But it doesn't work. Any help will be appreciated. I want to block search engine **http://search.pch.com** either through **.htaccess** or some other method.

**UPDATE**
I have also tried this one

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
```

no effect

Comment: it might help: http://www.wikihow.com/Block-Search-Engines

Comment: i also used this one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into your log-files on your webserver to check if `http://search.pch.com` is the User-agent of the crawler.

Use a robot.txt (not reboot.txt) with

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

instead if you like any bots (that respect robot.txt) not to crawl you page.

Comment: i think it will block all search engines . i only wants to block http://search.pch.com

Answer (score 0):

First: file name should be robot.txt

Second: its web crawlers choice whether to honor this file. It clearly says "most of"

Third and most important: the user agent string for the PCHSearch might not be the same as its url. double check the user agent string.

or you can use [this](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1699/Block+a+specific+IP+address+from+accessing+your+website#gs) code for htaccess

```
# block visitors referred from indicated domains
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} baddomain01\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} baddomain02\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "http://search.pch\.com" bad_referer

Order Allow,Deny
Allow from ALL
Deny from env=bad_referer
```